# Android Studio multi module app - issue with Content Root

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, multi-module

I am learning how to create a multi-module Android app. 
I have created a new project and deleted the initial `app` module.
Then I added 2 pure Java/Kotlin modules: data and domain.

I have an issue that the content root of these modules is not recognized automatically when I invalidate the cache and restart Android Studio.

The Android Studio looks like this when it opens:
[image]

When I double-click on `data` or `domain` modules I see this window, which I cannot access later via File->Project Structure:
[image: `]

Answer (score 0):

If you have only pure Java/Kotlin modules that it's not an Android project anymore. I faced different issues running pure java/kotlin codes in AS. I know that they should be the same deep down but somehow Idea CE worked better for me when I tried something else than Android.

Comment: I plan to add Android framework modules as well in the future. I've deleted only `app` directory, not `build` because it is referenced in the Project structure as an output.